# which algorithm dominates f(n) or (g(n)

Tags: algorithm

I am doing an introductory course on algorithms. I've come across this problem which I'm unsure about.
I would like to know which of the 2 are dominant

f(n): 100n + log n  or g(n): n + (log n)^2

Given the definitions of each of:
Ω, Θ, O

I assumed f(n), so fn = Ω(g(n))
Reason being that n dominates (log n)^2, is that true?

Comment: @Krease Irrelevant. The `n`s don't cancel out; they just grow at the same rate to within a constant factor.

Comment: For this kind of questions I believe the ComputerScience StackExchange site is better suited. Although remember to first *search* and try to solve the problem on your own.

Comment: http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiJ4Kyhsb2coeCkpXjIiLCJjb2xvciI6IiMzMzAwRkYifSx7InR5cGUiOjAsImVxIjoiMTAwKngrbG9nKHgpIiwiY29sb3IiOiIjRkYwMDAwIn0seyJ0eXBlIjoxMDAwLCJ3aW5kb3ciOlsiMCIsIjEwMDAwIiwiLTEiLCIxMDAwMDAwIl19XQ--

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case,

*lim<sub>n → ∞</sub>[f(n) / g(n)] = 100*.

If you go over calculus definitions, this means that, for any *ε > 0*, there exists some *m* for which

*100  (1 - ε) g(n) ≤ f(n) ≤ 100  (1 + ε) g(n)*

for any *n > m*.

From the definition of *Θ*, you can infer that these two functions are *Θ* of each other.

---

In general, if

*lim<sub>n → ∞</sub>[f(n) / g(n)] = c* exists, and

*0 < c < ∞*,

then the two functions have the same order of growth (they are *Θ* of each other).

Answer (score 4):

`n` dominates both `log(n)` and `(log n)^2`

A little explanation

1. `f(n) = 100n + log n`

Here `n` dominates `log n` for large values of `n`.

So `f(n) = O(n)` .......... [1]

2. `g(n) = n + (log n)^2`

Now, `(log n)^2` dominates `log n`.

But `n` still dominates `(log n)^2`.

So `g(n) = O(n)` .......... [2]

Now, taking results [1] and [2] into consideration.

`f(n) = Θ(g(n)) and g(n) = Θ(f(n))`

since they will grow at the same rate for large values of `n`.

Answer (score 3):

We can say that `f(n) = O(g(n)` if there are constants `c > 0` and `n0 > 0` such that

```
f(n) <= c*g(n), n > n0
```

This is the case for both directions:

```
# c == 100
100n + log n <= 100(n + (log n)^2)
              = 100n + 100(log(n)^2)   (n > 1)
```

and

```
# c == 1
n + (log n)^2 <= 100n + log n    (n > 1)
```

Taken together, we've proved that `n + (log n)^2 <= 100n + log n <= 100(n + (log n)^2)`, which proves that `f(n) = Θ(g(n))`, which is to say that neither dominates the other. Both functions are `Θ(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

`g(n)` dominates `f(n)`, or equivalently, `g(n) is Ω(f(n))` and the same hold vice versa.

Considering the definition, you see that you can drop the factor 100 in the definition of `f(n)` (since you can multiply it by any **fixed** number) and you can drop both addends since they are dominated by the linear `n`.

The above follows from `n is Ω(n + logn)` and `n is Ω(n + log^2n`.

hope that helps,
fricke